# Not able to provide string variable for xAxisLabel or yAxisLabel in DC.JS charts

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am plotting a line chart using `DC.js`
I am providing label to my **yAxis** like

```
chart.yAxisLabel("Time");
```

Its working fine in this way.

But in my application I support localization so I am giving a String variable with the label. This is not working

```
var label = "Time";
chart.yAxisLabel(label);
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more of your code. Obviously the exact example you give [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/4or7kdgf/9/), because it's equivalent. Probably something else is going wrong like you have asynchronous code so `label` is not set when `xAxisLabel` is called, or something like that.

Comment: Er, `yAxisLabel` - same difference.

Comment: Now this started working, I think it was asynchronous code problem only